# Book about a character born in-between time on some sort of timeship

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, parallel-universe

I can't find the name of this book! I believe it's YA. I read it at least 5 years ago, probably more.

The main character was born in between time on some sort of timeship. His mother had gotten pregnant with him with a man in the Roman (?) time period, and gave birth to him on the timeship while traveling back to her original time (in the future).

There's a scene at the beginning of the book where the main character is trying to check into an appointment that asks for his birthday. He tries different combos of "no birthday" "born on a time ship" and born in (Roman time) and (current time), but none of them work. His friend who works at the office comes out and fixes the machine for his non-existent birthday.

The plot of the book has something to do with a multiverse. I believe a copy of the protagonist from another universe is searching for someone/thing that's making the multiverse unstable, and it's eventually revealed to be the protagonist because he was born in between times. While this is being discovered, the protagonist and his friends are traveling back in time (I can't remember the reason why).

Thanks for your help! This has been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this ***[Invictus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33152795-invictus)*** (2017) by Ryan Graudin...?

The Goodreads plot summary notes that the protagonist, Farway "Far" McCarthy, was born outside of time and is the son of a time-traveller from the future and a gladiator from Ancient Rome.

> **Farway Gaius McCarthy was born outside of time. The son of a time-traveling Recorder from 2354 AD and a gladiator living in Rome in 95 AD, Far's birth defies the laws of nature.** Exploring history himself is all he's ever wanted, and after failing his final time-traveling exam, Far takes a position commanding a ship with a crew of his friends as part of a black market operation to steal valuables from the past.
>
> But during a heist on the sinking Titanic, Far meets a mysterious girl who always seems to be one step ahead of him. Armed with knowledge that will bring Far's very existence into question, she will lead Far and his team on a race through time to discover a frightening truth: History is not as steady as it seems.

This [review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/ryan-graudin/invictus/) notes that Far was born on a time-travelling ship, and that he encounters a mysterious girl named Eliot, who's on a mission to save the multiverse from being devoured by something called the Fade. Comparing this with the Goodreads summary, it appears that he met her during a heist on the sinking Titanic.

> A boy born beyond time and space finds he is running out of time to save the worlds.
> **Born aboard a time-traveling ship, 17-year-old Farway Gaius McCarthy dreams of being a Recorder like his missing mother, Empra McCarthy.** Ejected from the Academy, Far goes rogue, working as an antiquities thief for a black-market baron. Acting as captain and Recorder of the Invictus, Far and his teenage crew—Historian Imogen, Far’s rainbow-haired cousin; Engineer Gram, a math genius; and Medic Priya, Far’s love interest—plus a mischievous red panda go on excellent adventures. But **they alter their course after encountering the mysterious Eliot, a girl on a grim mission to stop the Fade from devouring the multiverse.**

Judging by an excerpt from the book included in this [article](https://ew.com/books/2017/02/21/ryan-graudin-invictus/) (which also includes an interview with the author), it begins with Far attending an appointment with a medic, but being confronted by a med-droid that requested his date of birth (among other information); a question he couldn't correctly answer, as he technically had no date of birth. This was apparently a recurring problem, and a human medic had to come out of the examination room and rewire the droid to bypass the question manually.

> May 5, 2371
>
> “State your name.” The med-droid’s automated voice was cut clean, every syllable filed down to replicate a Central accent.
>
> [...]
>
> “Farway Gaius McCarthy,” he answered.
>
> **The med-droid recorded the reply, shifted seamlessly into the next question. “State your date of birth.”**
>
> **Far sighed. They asked this question. Every. Single. Time. And every single time he answered, the med-droid’s computers would whir through the census databases, find nothing, and state in its elegant accent: “Answer invalid. Restate your date of birth.”**
>
> [...]
>
> **The examination room door slid open. A living Medic stuck her head around the corner.** Her features were as edged and elegant as the Hindi on her ID card. A stethoscope dangled from her neck, competing for space with gold-tinted headphones. “Is something wrong—oh!” Her face brightened. “Hello, Far!”
>
> “Hey, Priya.” He grinned at the Medic and tried oh-so-subtly to tense his abdominal muscles.
>
> [...]
>
> **“Ah. Birth date question again?”**
>
> **“Never not,” Far said.**
>
> **Being a Medic in an age where droids made up fifteen percent of the population required training beyond human biology, so like most of her peers, Priya doubled as a mechanic. She pried open the med-droid’s chest plate and rearranged some wires—a routine Far had seen her perform scores of time—to bypass the question manually.** “You’d think they’d have this bug fixed by now.”
>
> <sub>*Invictus* (2017) by Ryan Graudin</sub>

Comment: it is, thank you for your help!